# Generate orphan mesh in abaqus python

Tags: python, mesh, abaqus, orphan

I am trying to generate an orphan mesh on a part with python.
I have already defined the nodes by using a code giving by Tim in another post.

However, the with the following command:
ListElem.append(myTrabPart.Element(nodes=tup,elemShape=HEX8)

I ended up by the message "there is no mesh to edit". It seems that the ListElem is empty in my case. The list lengths are correct.
Do you have any advice which could help me?

Thanks,

Romain

Comment: if you are referencing some other post you should provide a link. This is not a sufficient code snipped to interpret.

Comment: This is the previuos post mentioned [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130774/generating-a-orphan-mesh-from-scratch-in-abaqus-with-python?rq=1). Have you followed the answers given in the linked question? you need to give more info if you want some help.

Answer (score 0):

In Abaqus you can only edit Native Meshes. This time, as you said, you have an Orphan Mesh. The only way to edit this kind of mesh is doing it by yourself with an external script.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually what I had to do was to define the orphan mesh before defining any part based on geometric (sketch) object.